# Solving a simple rational equation $(\frac{6x}{6-x})^2+x^2=400$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Clearly we could multiply both sides of
$$\left(\dfrac{6x}{6-x}\right)^2+x^2=400$$
by $(6-x)^2$ which leads to a degree 4 polynomial equation, which we can solve using the bi-quadratic formula. Moreover, we could approximate the solutions using Newtons method.  However, I have a feeling there is a much more graceful way to solve this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: +1) First step: Multiply through both sides by $(6-x)^2$ I wouldn't see another way algebraically...(although if I am not mistaken, there is a formula to solve 4th degree equations)

Comment: @imranfat thanks I see that.. I noted we could multiply by $(6-x)^2$ and use the degree 4 formula.. but I have a feeling there are more elegant ways to do this..

Comment: Through graphing, is there a rational solution?

Comment: Check the graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/98fjpmhyb4

This equation only has ugly solutions.

Comment: i got $$\frac{36x^2}{x^2+12x+36}=(20+x)(20-x)$$

Comment: thank you, both, I could check the graph, but I was actually hoping for a more elegant solution that the one I suggested, the approximation using the graph is unfulfilling....

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2020139/solve-the-equation-x2-frac9x2x32-27

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quartic (or bi-quadratic) polynomial for $x$ can be factored into two quadratic polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{109}]$, so that the closed-form expression for roots is not as terrible as it can be generally.

Clearing fractions one gets:

$$ x^4 - 12x^3 - 328x^2 + 4800x - 14400 = 0 $$

Then notice that:

$$ x^4 - 12x^3 - 328x^2 + 4800x - 14400 = (x^2 - Ax + 6A)(x^2 - Bx + 6B) $$

provided $A+B = 12$ and $AB = -400$.

It follows that the roots for $x$ may be found by solving the respective quadratic equations with $A = 6 + 2\sqrt{109}$ and $B = 6 - 2\sqrt{109}$.

More explicitly:

$$ x = 3 - \sqrt{109} \pm \sqrt{82 + 6\sqrt{109}}\;,\; 3 + \sqrt{109} \pm \sqrt{82 - 6\sqrt{109}} $$

A crude estimate shows that the expressions under the radicals are all positive, and thus the four roots are indeed real roots.

**How was the reducibility of the polynomial recognized?**

Initially I saw that setting $y = \frac{6x}{x-6}$ leads to a system of equations:

$$ x^2 + y^2 = 20^2 $$

$$ (x - 6)(y - 6) = 36 $$

Geometrically this asks for the intersection of a circle of radius $20$ centered at the origin and a "right" hyperbola with center $(6,6)$.  Since both curves are symmetric about the line $y = x$, it follows that when $(x,y)$ is a point of intersection, so too is $(y,x)$.

Algebraically this amounts to saying that $x \mapsto \frac{6x}{x-6}$ is an involution which pairs up the roots $x$.  A bit of scratchwork showed that the pairing of roots in this way results in factors $x^2 - Ax + 6A$ and $x^2 - Bx + 6B$ where $A,B$ are roots of $w^2 - 12w - 400 = 0$.

Comment: excellent idea, thank you!  how did you see that $x^4 - 12x^3 - 328x^2 + 4800x - 14400 = (x^2 - Ax + 6A)(x^2 - Bx + 6B)$ might have a solution? I suppose generally one may try $x^4 - 12x^3 - 328x^2 + 4800x - 14400 = (x^2 - Ax +B)(x^2 + Cx + D)$  but $x^4 - 12x^3 - 328x^2 + 4800x - 14400 = (x^2 - Ax + 6A)(x^2 - Bx + 6B)$ seems like wizardy without knowing the roots already, or did you try $x^4 - 12x^3 - 328x^2 + 4800x - 14400 = (x^2 - Ax +B)(x^2 + Cx + D)$  first, then chip away at the unknown constants?I think the solution is  beautiful but I think there is more I can learn from this...  thx

Comment: @userX: Sure, I wanted to give the result as quickly as I could and deferred until a few moments ago disclosing the discovery process.  Have a look and feel free to ask if something further is wanted.

Comment: excellent!  thank you very much for your help and for clarifying how you recognized the factorization form.

Comment: How did you get $(x-6)(y-6)=36$?

Comment: @Ovi:  From the substitution, $y = 6x/(x-6)$, it follows $xy - 6y = 6x$.  Then you collect terms and complete the factorization by adding $36$ to both sides.

Answer (score 4):

Please note that,you have:
$\left(\dfrac{6x}{6-x}\right)^2+x^2=400$.......(A)

Now,
$[\left(\dfrac{6x}{6-x}\right) -x]^2$=
$\left(\dfrac{x^2}{6-x}\right)^2$=$400$-$12$$\left(\dfrac{x^2}{6-x}\right)$...[using $(a-b)^2$ identity followed by(A)]
Now put $t=\left(\dfrac{x^2}{6-x}\right)$ [Keeping in mind that $x\ne6$]and you get a quadratic in $t$ which gives you two values of $t$.Then equate each $t$ with $\left(\dfrac{x^2}{6-x}\right)$,solve for $x$.....etc.
P.S.:In case of difficulty ,please comment.

Comment: wow, that is very nice! thank you, how did you see that? is there a generalization of this idea?

Comment: +1 very nice! I also want to know how you invent this! Please, if respond use @Ovi in beginning so I can see too!

Comment: @Ovi,actually I tried to reduce it to a quadratic equation.

Comment: @userX,@Ovi ,I just $(a-b)^2$ identity and found that it simplified and I finally reduced it to a quadratic equation!!