# Find all the real roots of $ x^2 + x^2/(x+1)^2=3 $

Tags: quadratics

> Find all the real roots of $x^2 + \frac{x^2}{(x+1)^2}=3$.

I got a 4th power equation after simplifying but didn't understand what to do afterwards

Comment: I think it is a good idea to add the 4th degree equation you get to the question.

Comment: The real roots have exceptionally complicated forms (see [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2+%2B+x%5E2+%28x%2B1%29%5E2+-+3)), so I doubt there's must you really can do except using the quartic formula. I do notice you can factor $x^2$ on the left hand side, too, but I don't think you'll get anywhere useful that way. I imagine the best you can realistically do is approximate

Comment: Is it $x^2+x^2(x+1)^2=3$ or is it $x^2+\frac{x^2}{(x+1)^2}=3$? Be clear.

Comment: THE SECOND ONE.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solve the equation $x^2+\frac{9x^2}{(x+3)^2}=27$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2020139/solve-the-equation-x2-frac9x2x32-27)

Comment: The substitution $t=1+x$ bring your equation to a more symmetric form $(1-t)^2+\left(1-\dfrac1t\right)^2=3.$ In particular, this shows that if $t$ is a solution, then $\dfrac1t$ is also a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Factorize the equation as follows

\begin{align}
0= & x^2 + \frac{x^2}{(x+1)^2}-3\\=& \frac1{(1+x)^2}\left(x^2(x+1)^2+x^2-3(x+1)^2 \right) \\
= &\frac1{(1+x)^2}\left(x^4 +2(x+1)x^2-3(x+1)^2 \right) \\
= &\frac1{(1+x)^2}(x^2-(x+1))(x^2+3(x+1)) \\
\end{align}
which, from the factor $x^2-x-1$, yields the real solution
$$x=\frac12\pm \frac{\sqrt5}2$$

Answer (score 1):

$x^2+\frac{x^2}{(x+1)^2}=3$ (x≠1)

$\Rightarrow x^2+\frac{x^2}{(x+1)^2}-3=0$

Which simplifies as
$\frac{x^4+2x^3-x^2-6x-3}{(x+1)^2}=0$

$\Rightarrow x^4+2x^3-x^2-6x-3=0$

Factorising, we get

$(x^2-x-1)(x^2+3x+3)=0$

For which we get two equations to solve

$x^2-x-1=0$

$x^2+3x+3=0$

Solving the first eqn. we get $x=\frac{1±\sqrt{5}}{2}$
The second equation has no (real) solution.

$\therefore x=\frac{1±\sqrt{5}}{2}$

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

$$x^2 + \frac{x^2}{(x+1)^2}=3\implies \frac{x^2}{x^2+2x+1}+x^2-3= 0\\ \implies x^2+(x^4+2x^3+x^2)-(3x^2+6x+3)\\
 = x^4 + 2 x^3 - x^2 - 6 x - 3=0\\
\text{ which factors as follows}\\
=(x^2 - x - 1) (x^2 + 3 x + 3) = 0$$

Both of these can be solve by the quadratic equation.

$$(x^2 - x - 1)=0\quad x =\frac{(1 \pm \sqrt{5})}{2}\approx 0.618\lor1.618=\phi$$

The other two roots are complex.

Comment: BUT HOW TO ATTEMPT THEM IN EXAM

Comment: In which exam are you supposed to solve a fourth degree eqn by hand?

Comment: You can approximate the intervals in which the roots lie, by checking the signs of f(x) for certain integer values.

Comment: You should perhaps edit your question to include the context.

Comment: @poetasis The equation you solved is the wrong one, OP changed it

Comment: @Ottavio Bartenor Thanks, I'll take a look and edit my answer.