# Finding the range of $x$ such that $x^2+\frac{x^{2}}{(x+1)^2}<\frac54$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Find the range of $x$:
> $$x^2+\frac{x^{2}}{(x+1)^2}<\frac54$$

I am confused about a good approach to this question. My teacher says a graphical approach is the most convenient one, but isn't there any other method to find the range?

Answer (score 1):

$$ x^2 +\frac{x^2}{(x+1)^2} \lt \frac 54 \\ \iff x^2(x+1)^2 +x^2 \lt \frac 54 (x+1)^2 \\ \iff x^4 +2x^3 +2x^2 \lt \frac 54 (x^2 +2x +1) \\ \iff x^4 +2x^3 +\frac 34 x^2 -\frac 52 x -\frac 54 \lt 0  \\ \iff 4x^4 +8x^3 +3x^2 -10x -5 \lt 0$$ $1$ is a root, so factor. $$\iff (x-1)(4x^3 +12x^2+15x+5) \lt 0 $$ $-\frac 12$ is a root of the cubic, so factor. $$\iff (x-1)(x+\frac 12) (4x^2+10x+10)\lt 0$$ The quadratic has a negative discriminant  and hence is always positive. $$\iff (x-1)(x+\frac 12) \lt 0 \\ \iff -\frac 12 \lt x \lt 1$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Like [Solve the equation $x^2+\frac{9x^2}{(x+3)^2}=27$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2020139/solve-the-equation-x2-frac9x2x32-27/2020168#2020168),

$$x^2+\left(\dfrac x{x+1}\right)^2=\left(x-\dfrac x{x+1}\right)^2+2\cdot\dfrac{x^2}{x+1}$$

If $\dfrac{x^2}{x+1}=a,$ we have $$a^2+2a<\dfrac54\iff(a+1)^2<\dfrac94\iff-\dfrac32<a+1<\dfrac32$$

Answer (score 0):

> but isn't there any other method to find the range?

First I derived the minimums of $f(x)$. Very easy task finding $x=-2$ and $x=0$

Then by simple inspection (I spent 30'' to do that) immediately find that the range such that $f(x)<1.25$ is given by

$$x \in (-0.5;1)$$

The suggested graphical method is easy too...

[image]

the red line is $y=5/4$

the blue line is the graphics of your $f(x)$

to calculate the two bounds I think it is evident that

$$f(1)=1+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{5}{4}$$

$$f(-0.5)=\frac{1}{4}+1=\frac{5}{4}$$

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how you did the inspection?

Comment: @Amritpal_Singh :  being RHS $1+1/4$ is is evident for me that $f(1)$ works. Being $f(-1)=\infty$ I began trying $f(-0.5)$ and it worked too....you can try 2 or 3 times and sure you will get the exact values